# Git completing cherry pick

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-cherry-pick

I'm currently trying to complete a cherry pick on Git and I have come to a point where I don't know what to do, and Google is not helping either :).

These are my steps:

1. Started cherry-pick process in Sourcetree
2. Resolved my conflicts
3. Opened the terminal and did a git cherry-pick --continue
4. An editor opens, I added some comments however I have no idea what to do afterwards.

I click enter, esc and nothing happens.  Below is a screen shot of what I see, any help on how can I finish the cherry will be greatly appreciated.

[image: terminal screen shot]

Comment: Do you know how to use vim?

Comment: Nope :( I'm fairly new to git

Comment: Vim is not git, it is a separate terminal based text editor. It opens by default when you add a commit message to git. See my answer for how to save the file in vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you have vim terminal open. Press the `Esc` key, then type `:wq` and hit enter to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks! and what a silly way of vim!